# com.arangodb.velocypack.exception.VPackParserException: java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arangodb

i am trying to connect my ArangoDb database with scala, but when the connection is made, and i am doing the operation, i have an VPackParserException error. My code:

```
import com.arangodb.spark.{ArangoSpark, ReadOptions}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

object ArangotoSpark {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  case class netflow(@BeanProperty SrcHost: String,
                   @BeanProperty DstHost: String,
                   @BeanProperty SrcPort: String,
                   @BeanProperty DstPort: String,
                   @BeanProperty Protocol: String,
                   @BeanProperty StartTS: String,
                   @BeanProperty EndTS: String,
                   @BeanProperty Packets: Int,
                   @BeanProperty Bytes: Int) {  }

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("arangodb.host", "127.0.0.2")
    .set("arangodb.port", "8529")
    .set("arangodb.user", "root")
    .set("arangodb.password", "rut")
    .set("arangodb.database", "netflow")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val rdd = ArangoSpark.load[netflow](sc, "N201701031130", ReadOptions("netflow"))
  val rdd2 = rdd.filter { x => x.SrcHost.matches("15.33.165.30") }
  rdd2.count()
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Now my code looks like this:

```
case class nf (@BeanProperty cadena: String){
   def this() = this(cadena = null)}
val rdd = ArangoSpark.load[nf](sc, "N201701031130", ReadOptions("netflow"))
println(rdd.count())
println("*************************************")
rdd.collect.foreach(println(_))
```

rdd.count gives the correct number of documents, but when i try to print them, i only have *nf(null)* lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class `netflow` needs a parameterless constructor.

The VelocyPack deserializer which deserialize incoming VelocyPack into Java/Scala objects - under the hood of the Java driver - needs it to instantiate your class.

**update:**

You don't have to parse it to work with the field names. Your case class can have the same fields as the stored documents. The serializer/deserializer from the java driver can work with it. But you also need a parameterless constructor.

Your case class could look as follow:

```
case class netflow(@BeanProperty SrcHost: String,
                   @BeanProperty DstHost: String,
                   @BeanProperty SrcPort: String,
                   @BeanProperty DstPort: String,
                   @BeanProperty Protocol: String,
                   @BeanProperty StartTS: String,
                   @BeanProperty EndTS: String,
                   @BeanProperty Packets: Int,
                   @BeanProperty Bytes: Int) {
  def this() = this(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)}
}
```

Comment: .i tried this and it works:
    case class nf (cadena: String){
         def this() = this(cadena = null)
     }

Comment: So i have to parse it to work with field names. Thank you

Comment: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Int
    def this() = this(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)}

Comment: Changing the type in *load* method to String is working: `ArangoSpark.load[String](sc, "N201701031130", ReadOptions("netflow"))`